# Call to a member function hashName() on string error when use putFile() to storing a file via url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm working on an API that users can send a file url to download it to their specific folder that has a name same as their usernames.

First I added new disk option to filesystem configuration named `user` that holds specific directory same name as authenticated user username. like this:

```
    'disks' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => NULL, //set on the fly after user authentication. (LogAuthenticated.php)
        ],
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path('files'),
        ]
    ]
```

When a User authenticate, I creates a directory named same as authenticated username on listener of `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated` event and set `filesystems.disks.user.root` config  like this :

```
    public function handle (Authenticated $event)
    {
        $username = $event->user->username;

        if (!Storage::exists($username)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($username, 0775);
        }
        Config::set('filesystems.disks.user.root', public_path('files/' . $username));
    }
```

Now I want to store a file from an external url that user provided.
Suppose that file has `jpg` format and I want to store that in `photo` directory on user Directory with a unique name. for that I wrote this :

```
Storage::disk('user')->putFile('photos', fopen($photo, 'r'));
```

But when I run code got this error:

```
Call to a member function hashName() on string
```

I do not know what is this error and why occured. if anyone know please help me.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#storing-files), you could use:

```
Storage::disk('user')->putFile('photos', new \Illuminate\Http\File($photo));
```

If photo is a URL, you could try:

```
Storage::disk('user')->put('file.jpg', file_get_contents($photo));
```

Comment: I tried `Storage::disk('user')->putFile('photos', new File($photo));` but in this case got this error : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\File::hashName()`

Comment: `$photo` is a url string. does `new File()` accept this type of parameter?

Comment: @A.B.Developer OK, fixed for URL

Comment: `Storage::disk('user')->put('file.jpg', file_get_contents($photo));` worked. but : I want laravel assign a uuid name to file . in this case I must to specify a file name in first parameter of put() method. how can I do that ?